# Getting a list of Channel Ids that belong to a YouTube Content Owner

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Given a content owner id is there a way I can retrieve a list of channels in that parent that I can then provide in the "channels" filter, through any of the apis?

For example using the content id, you can retrieve all the views across the network like so:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?start-date=2013-03-01&end-date=2013-03-02&ids=contentOwner=={CONTENT_OWNER_ID}&metrics=views&filters=uploaderType==self&key=etc...
```

however I would like to get a list of channel ids that could possibly be used in the channels filter (&filters=channel==long_channel_string_here).

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're talking about? What "content owner id" are you talking about?

Comment: I updated the question with an example. The content owner id is the one that is used for YouTube Partners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `managedByMe` parameter when making a `youtube.channels.list()` call, as documented at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#managedByMe